# how to add a new set to vector c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to add a new set to my vector here is my code

```
set<string>::iterator iter;
vector<set<string> > myVector;
set<string> mySet;

mySet.insert("hello");
myVector.push_back(mySet);
mySet.clear();
mySet.insert("world");
myVector.push_back(mySet);

cout << mySet.size() << endl;
cout << myVector.size() << endl;
// printing out vector of sets
for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    for (iter = mySet.begin(); iter != mySet.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The output is

```
    1
    2
    world
    world
```

Am I printing or implementing incorrectly?  I want it to print

```
    1
    2
    hello
    world
```

Comment: Use `myVector[i]` instead of `mySet` in the for loop.

Comment: although you are iterating over the elements in the vector, you are always using mySet in the body of the loop. You need something like set<string>& set_i = myVector[i]; to access the set for each iteration

Comment: thank you very much it is working now, is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: in general reusing containers is asking for trouble. if you're using c++11 you should use for (auto s : myVector) {} to iterate over the vector and then for (auto s_elem : s ) to iterate over the set in the inner loop.. less typing and clearer!!

Comment: @Jimmy I think my prof uses c98 for the test cases so I have to use all these for loops.  Is there a better way to add a new set to the vector without reusing it?  My strategy so far has been adding whatever's in the temp then using .clear() and then reusing.  This is my first time using stl containers so any advice would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not printing the vector values

```
for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    for (iter = myVector[i].begin(); iter != myVector[i].end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```